# My Observer invoke in windows but not in linux

Tags: event-observer

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <RayMan_Adminlog>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <title>Admin log module</title>
        </RayMan_Adminlog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <adminlog>
                <class>RayMan_Adminlog_Model</class>            
                <resourceModel>adminlog_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </adminlog>
            <adminlog_mysql4>
                <class>RayMan_Adminlog_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <adminlog>
                        <table>admin_log</table>
                    </adminlog>
                </entities>
            </adminlog_mysql4>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <adminlog>
                <class>RayMan_Adminlog_Helper</class>
            </adminlog>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <adminlog>
                <class>RayMan_Adminlog_Block</class>
            </adminlog>
        </blocks>
        <default>
            <adminlog>
                <general>
                    <enable>1</enable>
                </general>
            </adminlog>
        </default>

    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminlog>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>RayMan_Adminlog</module>
                    <frontName>adminlog</frontName>
                </args>
            </adminlog>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <adminlog>
                <file>adminlog.xml</file>
            </adminlog>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <events>
        <sales_order_invoice_pay>
            <observers>
                <rayman_adminlog_controller_action_predispatch_observer>
                    <class>Rayman_Adminlog_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>sales_order_invoice_pay</method>
                </rayman_adminlog_controller_action_predispatch_observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_invoice_pay>
    </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Observer class:

```
<?php
class Rayman_Adminlog_Model_Observer
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
    /**
     * 
     * 
     * 
     */
    public function sales_order_invoice_pay($observer)
    {

      $event = $observer->getEvent();
      $eventName = $event->getName();
      $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write'); 
      $connection->beginTransaction();

      $__fields = array();
      $__fields['action'] = $eventName;
      $userData = $this->getAdmin();
      $username = $userData['user']->username;    
      $__fields['admin_name'] = $username;    
      $connection->insert('admin_log', $__fields);
      $connection->commit();      

      //return $this;
    }

    private function getCurrentAdminName() {

    }

    private function getAdmin() {
        $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getData();
        return $user;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please enable log in check error and please update the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your observer class name from

```
Rayman_Adminlog_Model_Observer
```

To

```
RayMan_Adminlog_Model_Observer
```

Linux is case sensitive.

Comment: i renamed All RayMan to Rayman, all problems fixed. thanks